# React SetState callback is synchronous

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple react component and iam playing with the state a little bit.

I noticed when i pressed the button, the "first" executes along with  "inside1". Afterwards "second" and then "HEYY STATE". I thought that setState executes asynchronously but it seems that the first one executes synchronously.

Why only the first callback is executed synchronously?

On React 17v.

```
const Test= () => {

  const [test, setTest] = useState(0);

  console.log("HEYY STATE", test);

  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={() => {
        setTest((e) => {
          console.log("first", e);
          return 1;
        });

        setTest((e) => {
          console.log("second", e);
          return 2;
        });
        console.log("inside1");
    
      }}
    >
      Hello
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't see a question being asked.

Comment: Does it print "HEYY STATE 1", "HEYY STATE 2", or both?

Comment: @jsejcksnn Check the updated post

Comment: @DustInComp doesnt matter. What iam asking is why only the first callback is executed synchronously?

Comment: Seems to vary actually, I tried logging timestamps as well on https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-agnesi-l6zgki?file=/src/App.js.
Looks like it also logs "inside1" first some of the time. Could be that React decides whether to handle the setter sync or async depending on when during an animation frame it is called to leave enough time for rendering.

Comment: You shouldn't be too concerned about the order here. React says that if you have multiple `setState` calls, then it will batch it together and apply one after the other, but it doesn't say anything about relative order with the outer function. Your application logic shouldn't be dependant on the order in which react will update and instead, it should be like when React does update, what do you want to do with it.  Also, if you want to force the `setState` update before proceeding to the next line, you can make use of `flushSync` function (but use it with caution).

Comment: @DustInComp From my side is always consistent "first" is always first. Even in codesandbox